# Валидация входящих данных с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, валидация, qregexp, сопоставление-с-образцом

Добрый день всем!
Не могу написать регулярное выражение что бы полностью провалидировать входящую строку согласно требований:

1. Латиница верхний нижний регистр (`[A-Za-z]`)
2. Пробел, запятая, тире.
3. Строка начинается и заканчивается с литеры (любой).
4. Тире только между литерами.
5. Запятая только перед пробелом после литеры

Моя версия регулярного выражения:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z]+\\s)*([A-Za-z]+\\,\\s)*([A-Za-z]+\\-[A-Za-z]+[\\,]*\\s)*[A-Za-z]+");
```

Comment: Как-то так, наверное: `^([A-Za-z]+(-|,\s+|\s+)?)*[A-Za-z]$`

Comment: Ваше выражение работает в точности как мне нужно, можете пояснить блок ```(-|,\s+|\s+)?)```

Comment: Вертикальная черта означает "или", т.е. здесь - или тире, или запятая и после нее один или несколько пробельных символов, или просто один или несколько пробельных символов. Знак вопроса после - блок в скобках может быть, а может и не быть.

Comment: В таком случае возможен сценарий когда после тире будет пробел, я попробовал такой сценарий и выражение его не пропустило - не могу понять почему?

Comment: нет такого сценария, тире стоит отдельно без пробелов до или после.

Comment: а, теперь вроде зашло, если я напишу (-|,\s|\s)?) это будет означать - либо тире либо запятая+пробел(один) либо просто пробел(один). СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
^[A-Za-z]+(?:(?:, |-)[A-Za-z]+)*$
```

В Java можно обойтись без `^` / `$` при использовании метода `matches()`:

```
s.matches("[A-Za-z]+(?:(?:, |-)[A-Za-z]+)*")
```

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/X8xlu2/1). Если между буквами может быть и пробел, замените `(?:, |-)` на `(?: |, |-)` (если пробел один) / `(?: +|, |-)` (если пробелов может быть несколько). Если вместо буквального пробела могут быть разные пробельные символы, замените   на `\s+`.

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[A-Za-z]+` - 1 и более букв
- `(?:` - начало группы, которая будет повторяться 0 и более раз

  - `(?:, |-)` - запятая с пробелом или тире
  - `[A-Za-z]+` - 1 и более букв
- `)*` - 0 и более повторов
- `$` - конец строки

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Ваше выражение не работает в варианте ```"RR-R, Com-pany I-nc"```

Comment: @Andrew [`^[A-Za-z]+(?:(?: +|, |-)[A-Za-z]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/X8xlu2/2) работает. *Если между буквами может быть и пробел, замените `(?:, |-)` на `(?: |, |-)` (если пробел один) / `(?: +|, |-)` (если пробелов может быть несколько).* Так как список требований неполон, ответ содержит примерное решение и советы по дальнейшей настройке выражения.

Comment: Спасибо, всё написано верно, это я не правильно понял написанное)